# Sendgrid image URL not showing but it's there

Tags: sendgrid

In the dashboard I designed the email with many *dynamic parameters* such as `{{name}}`.
In the email template I have an image, and for the `Link URL` in the editor, I put `{{product_photo}}`, and my server will send the link.

So when i get the email, there is a blank square **but the link for the photo is there and i can view it on any browser by right clicking and open.** but it won't show inside the email.

The email client is not the problem since non of them will show the image inside the email.

I canceled already the tracking, and it still won't show, only on click.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by replacing the `src` in the `html` in Sendgrid to `src="{{product_photo}}"`.
You can see the `html` code by clicking on the button in the editor.